# similarity measures for categorical data in data mining

Tags: data-mining, similarity

I am working on my assignment in which i have to mention 5 similarity measures for categorical and continuous data in data mining. As a beginner I tried my best and found SQUARE DISTANCE,EUCLIDEAN AND MANHATTAN measures for continuous data.The point where i stuck is measures for categorical data. Could any one please tell me the names of similarity measures for categorical data.

Comment: You mean for categorical data?

Comment: @JahKnows yes i meant categorical data

Comment: @JahKnows also correct me about measures for continuous data that i mention in question if i am wrong.

Comment: There is a paper that outlines similarity measures for categorical data: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c654/4a12fec2097bddc49adbb159426d9dc15d2c.pdf

Comment: @AlexK thank you but there is only one  measure (overlap distance) is mentioned.I found 12 to 15 more measures for categorical data, now i have to quote one example for any 2 measures and i am searching for last 2 hours but could not found any simple and clear example

Comment: Thank you guys for your support. I have done my assignment.